# Harddisk makes noise but Disk Utility says its healthy

Tags: 12.04, hardware, hard-drive

I am using seagate Barracuda Internal Desktop 500gb hard drive. From few months i found my hard drive makes some different noise(Crushing or like metal rubbing spinning disk) but so far all SMART tests passed and PC responds normally.I really need to know why is noise when hard drive is healthy. Is their any other tests which can identify minor problems in disk.

Comment: You need to define "noise"

Answer (score 1):

The Barracudas are known of making noise, this is a normal behavior. (Noise level can be between 28-34 dBA@1m, which is normal.)

Comment: Before when running windows vista i found nothing like this. I suspected some thing was wrong so i posted a question. I am clear now. Thank god i think i am on safer zone.